# TIGER/Line processing

Tags: shapefile, data-management, tiger

Does anyone know of scripts for merging TIGER/Line shp files? It is for extracting the road features only, but for the whole of USA.

They are provided as shp files for one county at a time here:
http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/

If anyone sells the data, a link is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are tools for uploading tiger data to PostGIS.  It might be a little easier to work with once it's in PostGIS.  Here are some links:

http://pylab.blogspot.com/2007/02/import-tiger-database-to-postgis.html
http://geoserver.org/display/GEOSDOC/Loading+TIGER+polygons+tigerpoly.pl

Here's a ruby script for parsing Tiger data:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TIGER

**Edit:**

So, you want a shape file for all the roads in the U.S.  I believe that would be a fairly large shp file.  Does it have to be from Tiger?  You can get the [major highways in the U.S.](http://www.lib.unc.edu/reference/gis/datafinder/index.html?search_type=show_category_contents&category_id=110&datalayers=1&start=51&keyword_country_territory=&keyword_state=&include_global_spatial_extent=&affiliate=&limit_to_afs=) from here.

It looks like [MapWindow](http://www.mapwindow.org/index.php) should allow you to merge shp files.  I believe [QuantumGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) does also.

Finally, [here is a free tool whose only purpose is to merge shp files](http://www.vdstech.com/geomerge.htm).  This looks perfect for what you want.

Comment: That looks like a real detour, if I want SHP files and don't have/use postgis or ruby.

Comment: Agree, all of US is too much. 3-4 parts would be needed or the 2 GB limit is broken. The "major highways" misses too many details - I know the dataset already.

Answer (score 2):

The `ogr2ogr` utility of [OGR](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs) will do the trick, here's an example adapted [from the FAQ](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQVector):

```
# loop through all of the shapefiles in the directory and load them
for i in $(ls *.shp); do
  ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' -a_srs "EPSG:4269" -nln merged_tiger_roads $i -update -append -skipfailures
done
```

This should produce a single `merged_tiger_roads.shp` from the collection of shapefiles. The FAQ has additional examples of batch merging if you need a more complex workflow.

Comment: Thanks, will look into this. If I remember correctly, roads are only a subset of the line-layers in TIGER, so a selection would be needed. There are also far too many non-relevant fields in the DBF, so a selection here would be needed too.

Comment: @scw How did this project turn out? Would be interested to see/hear about the results!

Comment: @TedTaylorofLife worked great for my purposes. I used a similar data layer in helping analyze road connectivity networks for a fire movement model, and it worked well for our needs. Today, I might use OpenStreetMap data for the same purpose, which is richer than TIGER in many locations.